# How to remove toolbar in chrome extension popup?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, popup

Need to remove toolbar in google chrome extension popup page

I'm working to create chrome extension in vuejs i add popup page but i need to remove tool bar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8GVc.png)

my code to open popup page

**app.js**

```
 el: "#app",
    data: structs.data,
    methods: {
        handleTipBtn: function () {

            this.createWindow();
            console.log('btn click')
            structs.btnClick()

        },

        createWindow: function () {
            chrome.windows.create({
                url: 'popup.html',
                type: "panel",
                width: 400,
                height: 700,
                left: 900,
                top: 200,
            }, function (window) {
          });
```

**in button**

```
<button class="tip-button" @click="handleTipBtn"  >
                Tips Left: <span > {{tipsLeft}}</span>
         </button>
```

Need to remove toolbar in my popup page what to do

Comment: `type: "panel"` is supported only in ChromeOS. Try `type: "popup"`.

Comment: yes i tried that but its not working.